Azure DevOps Pipelines: dotnet ef not working
I am trying to set up EF Core migrations within my build-pipeline. Reading through online documentation and examples leads me to believe that this should be a straightforward thing to accomplish, however I am getting stuck whilst still installing the tools.
I start by installing the tools as required:
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: Install EF Tool
    inputs:
      command: custom
      custom: 'tool'
      arguments: 'update --global dotnet-ef' 

Now this step (above) always succeeds, but frequently (not always though) it also comes with some additional information about the PATH variables:
"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" tool update --global dotnet-ef
Tools directory 'C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\.dotnet\tools' is not currently on the PATH environment variable.

You can add the directory to the PATH by running the following command:

setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\.dotnet\tools"

You can invoke the tool using the following command: dotnet-ef
Tool 'dotnet-ef' (version '8.0.7') was successfully installed.

Which caused me to add another step to update the PATH as instructed. This step also always success:
  - script: setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\.dotnet\tools"
    displayName: Add toolsdirectory to Path 

Now we get to the part where things go wrong. I verify that EF Core has been successfully installed by using dotnet ef, which should give the EF Core unicorn horsey output if everything is working as expected.
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: Verify EF installation
    inputs:
      command: custom
      custom: 'ef'  

but things come unstuck for reasons I cannot explain.
Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
    Possible reasons for this include:
      * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
      * You intended to execute a .NET program, but dotnet-ef does not exist.
      * You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.

##\[error\]Error: The process 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1




Are you using a Microsoft-hosted or self-hosted build agent? Windows agent, right?

Based on your description, it seemed that your pipeline was running a Windows self-hosted agent as the local service account of NetworkService. I could reproduce similar issue when running my pipeline on such an agent.

For this you may add a UseDotNet@2 task in front of the step to install dotnet ef, which could add C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\.dotnet\tools to global tool path.
pool: Default
#  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  system.debug: true

steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '8.x'
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Install EF Tool
  inputs:
    command: custom
    custom: 'tool'
    arguments: 'update --global dotnet-ef' 
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Verify EF installation
  inputs:
    command: custom
    custom: 'ef'





Anytime and glad to know the solution add UseDotNet works for you. Cheers.
